# accessing superclass object by subclass reference variable

Tags: java

why cant we access superclass object by subclass reference variable ..i have a code discussing my problem.

```
class A
{ 
     void    set()    
  {
    System.out.println("i am in a");
  }
}

class B extends A
{
   void set()
  {
    System.out.println("i am in b");
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {  
     A instance=new B(); //line 
     instance.set();  //this would call set() in B.
     B in=new A(); //But this line gives error
  }
}
```

Can anyone be of help?

Comment: Static methods are not polymorphic. In your code, `instance.set();` would call `set()` in class `A`. And it is bad practice to call static methods via an instance variable. You should call `A.set()` or `B.set()`. Of course, I'm guessing you don't actually want static methods.

Comment: Mentally replace `A` with `Animal` and B with `Bat`. This should make it clearer why java gets upset when you try to put an `Animal` in a `Bats` variable; you call the `.fly()` method on it (which `Bat` has but `Animal` doesn't) and and all hell breaks loose. [I'm assuming your use of static here is accidental, if not there is a lot more wrong here]

Comment: possible duplicate of [In java , can we pass superclass Object to subclass reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384547/in-java-can-we-pass-superclass-object-to-subclass-reference)

Comment: Yes,by mistake i wrote static in the set method! set is a non-static method!

Answer (score 2):

A subclass may have members that the superclass doesn't, therefore it is not allowed to assign a superclass instance to a subclass reference.
Imagine that `B` has another method, `subMethod()`. If you could assign an `A` instance to a `B` reference, you could write the following code:

```
B example = new A();
example.subMethod();
```

which would break, since `A` doesn't have the `subMethod()`.

The other way around is fine though, since a subclass always has everything the superclass has.

Also, note that `static` methods can't be overridden, only instance methods are polymorphic.

Comment: @user3779571: You're very welcome. Don't forget to upvote (when you have enough reputation) helpful answers and accept the one that you think best answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Take another example similar to your problem,

```
class Animal
{ 
     void set()    
  {
    System.out.println("i am in animal");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
   void set()
  {
    System.out.println("i am in dog");
  }
  void bark(){
  System.out.println("woof woof");
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {  
     Animal instance=new Dog(); //line 
     instance.set();  //this would call set() in B.
     Dog in=new Animal(); //But this line gives error
  }
}
```

Inheritance follows a `is-a` relationship, now we can say Dog extends Animal and Dog is-a Animal. that makes sense. But Animal is-a Dog does not make sense.

When you write `Animal instance=new Dog();` , You are assigning a Dog object to a Animal reference , which sounds intuitive, also the LHS (Animal instance)  is the reference variable , and the job of the reference variable is to decide what functions to call on the object(Those present in Animal like set()) , You cannot call the `bark()` method using instance , because it is of type Animal reference, yes but you can call `set()` since it is present in Animal class. Now there are two version of `set()` one present in class Animal and class Dog, now which one to call depends on RHS (new Dog();) , since RHS is an instance and is of type `Dog()`, the version of `set()` in Dog will be called. To summarize, see the following code and output in comments:-

```
Animal a1=new Animal();
a.set();// output- i am in animal

Dog d1=new Dog();
d.set(); //output- i am in dog
d.bark; //valid and output- woof woof

Animal a2=new Dog();
a2.set();//output- i am in dog
a2.bark();// compilation error, you cannot refer to this method since it is not present in Animal class.

Dog d2=new Animal(); // compilation error
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is hierarchical.

You can create a class `Person` and a class `Karl extends Person`, with `sayName()` method,

then when you create a `Karl` it will fit into `Person` variables, but not every `Person` is a `Karl`.

If you want to explicitly call the superclass you could create a function `saySuperName()` in class `Karl`, where you call `super.sayName()`.

See also : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html